# Is there some kind of security issue in this code?

Tags: c, security

This is my code:

```
void handle(int s)
{
char inbuf[4096];//we defined inbuf as 4096 size

dup2(s, 0);
dup2(s, 1);

setbuf(stdout, NULL);

alarm(ALARM_TIMEOUT_SEC);

printf("crackme> ");

if (NULL == fgets(inbuf, sizeof(inbuf), stdin)) {
    return;
}

right_trim(inbuf);

if (is_correct(inbuf)) {
    printf("Good job!\n");
}
}
```

And if there is, what is the problem?
Little explanation about this program:
The first part of her running Server
When someone connects to the server and enter an input (i did a loop to examine the length of the input)
So this function looks at it and if the pass is correct then its print "good job"

Comment: I believe it's impossible to answer this since all code isn't shown.

Comment: I ascked on this particular Piece of the code...

Comment: I do not think this is a code review site. Try [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I have an uneasy sense of issues in `right_trim()`.

Comment: Whenever I see signals used the needle on my Heisenbug probability meter jumps around 85%.

Answer (score 0):

Answering the question as titled: yes. The use of

```
void setbuf(FILE *stream, char *buffer);
```

is deprecated due to security issues, and is retained by MSVC only for compatibility purposes. Please use

```
int setvbuf(FILE *stream, char *buffer, int mode, size_t size);
```

which is more secure since the buffer `size` is also provided (as well as more flexibility by providing `mode`) and it returns a function value to indicate success or failure.